# popToRootViewControllerAnimated not always firing viewWillAppear in rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

My application handles opening email attachments. To do this in my `AppDelegate` I call my dedicated ViewController which is the `RootViewController` of my App thanks to     `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`.

I do some treatments in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` of RootViewController but they are not called if the view controller that was displayed before switching to the mail application was my RootViewController!

**Case 1 : Usual viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear methods aren't called :**
*(RootViewController -> switch to Mail App -> Open attachement in my app -> in AppDelegate popToRootViewControllerAnimated -> RootViewController)*

**Case 2 : Usual viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear methods are called :**
*(OtherViewController -> switch to Mail App -> Open attachement in my app -> in AppDelegate popToRootViewControllerAnimated -> RootViewController)*

Found on the internet this trick but it doesn't work in case 1: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/viewWillAppear.html

**How can I fix this and call usual viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear methods all the time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view controller is already visible so it's normal that viewWillAppear doesn't get called.

If you want to know when the user gets back to your app just add the following code in RootViewController init method :

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                       selector:@selector(willEnterForeground:)
                                           name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                         object:nil];
```

and implement what you want in

```
- (void)willEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Don't forget to stop observing on when RootViewController will be deallocated :

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Your solution sounds great but how to know when `RootViewController` will be deallocated? When `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method is fired?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is because in Case 1, within the context of your app your RootViewController is already 'visible' and therefor `popToRootViewController` doesn't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` methods are called only when such a thing happens relative to your application. These methods are not called when you switch between applications. You should depend on the `applicationWillEnterForeground:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` methods in your appDelegate.

One more thing to note is that when you are doing

`RootViewController -> popToRootViewControllerAnimated -> RootViewController`

Your root view controller's view is already visible and thus it will not fire the `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` methods.

I recommend you do something similar to this

```
RootViewController.m

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self doSomething];
}

-(void)doSomething
{
   //Your functionality
}

AppDelegate.m

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [self.window.rootViewController doSomething];
}
```

You can also add your root view controller as a listener to the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`